# Move a specific number of files from a folder to another one (by oldest)

Tags: linux, shell-script, files, move

I am currently using this shell to move 25 files to another folder automatically.
But It moves files by alphabetical order, that's my main concern.
I would like the oldest files to be moved first instead.

```
i=0
for x in *; do
  if [ "$i" = 25 ]; then break; fi
  mv -- "$x" /my/other/folder/
  i=$((i+1))
done
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to use `zsh`?

Comment: Yes but I am a bit scared to switch. I am running so much Bash scripts on my server.